# Controlling a stepper motor with a Tkinter GUI - motor not turning?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi3, gpio, motordriver

I'm trying to run a small 28BYJ48 stepper motor from my raspberry pi3. I want to be able to start and stop the motor turning using a tkinter GUI. If I run this code in isolation, the motor turns fine:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
control_pins = [7,11,13,15]
for pin in control_pins:
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin, 0)

halfstep_seq = [[1,0,0,1],
       [1,0,0,0],
       [1,1,0,0],
       [0,1,0,0],
       [0,1,1,0],
       [0,0,1,0],
       [0,0,1,1],
       [0,0,0,1]]

StepCount = len(halfstep_seq)
StepCounter = 0
StepDir = 2

while True:
    for halfstep in range(8):
        for pin in range(4):
            GPIO.output(control_pins[pin],halfstep_seq[halfstep][pin])
        time.sleep(0.001)
        StepCounter += StepDir
        if (StepCounter>=StepCount):
            StepCounter = 0
        if (StepCounter<0):
            StepCounter = StepCount+StepDir

GPIO.cleanup
```

but if I run this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()
root.title("Superscope")
root.geometry("400x400")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

control_pins = [7,11,13,15]

control_pins_state = True

def start_motor():
    global control_pins_state
    for pin in control_pins:
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(pin, 0)

    halfstep_seq = [[1,0,0,1],
           [1,0,0,0],
           [1,1,0,0],
           [0,1,0,0],
           [0,1,1,0],
           [0,0,1,0],
           [0,0,1,1],
           [0,0,0,1]]

    StepCount = len(halfstep_seq)
    StepCounter = 0
    StepDir = 2

    #global StepCount, StepCounter, StepDir
    if control_pins_state==True:
        for halfstep in range(8):
            for pin in range(4):
                GPIO.output(control_pins[pin], halfstep_seq[halfstep][pin])
                time.sleep(0.0001)
                StepCounter += StepDir
                if (StepCounter<=StepCount):
                    control_pins_state = False

                #time.sleep(0.0001)
                #StepCounter += StepDir

        #if we reach the end of the sequence start again
    #if (StepCounter>=StepCount):
        #StepCounter = 0
    #if (StepCounter<0):
        #StepCounter = StepCount+StepDir

    #GPIO.cleanup()

def stop_motor():

    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__=="__main__":
    startbutton=tk.Button(root, width=10,height=1,text="Start",command=start_motor)
    stopbutton=tk.Button(root, width=10,height=1,text="Stop",command=stop_motor)
    startbutton.grid(row=1,column=0)
    stopbutton.grid(row=2,column=0)
```

The motor doesn't seem to turn on properly or move at all. Only one light on the driver board comes on with the second code, rather than two lights with the first code. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The indentation at `StepCounter += StepDir` doesn't match between the versions.  Also note the sleep duration is different.  To get a clean comparison the code should be the same except for the minimum change to enable the `Start` action.

Comment: Your GUI version only sets a single state; it doesn't loop through the states as the working version does, so no motor motion would be expected.  Now, you can't directly use that loop, as it would completely lock up the GUI (you would never be able to click the Stop button, for example).  You either need to run the loop in a separate thread, or continually schedule the next step via `.after()` to keep the motor moving.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that :)